# (Non) Rubber Band Pen Tool line preview won't show

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, pen-tool

I'm not new to Illustrator and I've already done some research.
I'm unsure why my problem is occurring and it's more or less a convenience issue.

When I am using the pen tool in Illustrator CC, a preview of where my line is and where my point is being dropped doesn't show up until after I've made the drop.

Unsure of exactly how to word that any better other than a preview guide of my path and hover point before clicking.

I have already tried hiding/showing edges as well as dipping into preferences to enable rubber band (but it was already enabled).

Comment: Note: that in many cases having that preview makes life harder to you. As now you have somewhat conflicting info on screen ON the other hand there is the preview, which is not showing you where the curve will be after final tweak. So it causes your brain to become encumbered with extra info which makes it harder for you to place the point where its optimal. So actually only showing it once you have the point placed is better in many cases, and teaches your brain more than the rubber band does.

Comment: I wish I could remove the above comment...what misinformed rubbish. The preview is how you know the line you are making will need less editing or even what you are doing. Drawing blind is certainly going to slow you down. Your brain is not that of a gerbil; you can process what you are drawing as you draw it; likely if a gerbil could draw it's brain could do this as well.

I found the best solution is restart the computer. it's all I got to work and I tried resetting settings; rubber band, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried resetting your preferences?

From the Adobe Help Site:

**Reset all preferences to default settings**

Resetting preferences can be helpful if you are having problems with the application.

Do one of the following:

1. Press and hold Alt+Control+Shift (Windows) or Option+Command+Shift (Mac OS) as you start Illustrator. Your current settings are deleted.
2. Remove or rename the AIPrefs file (Windows) or Adobe Illustrator Prefs file (Mac OS). New preferences files are created the next time you start Illustrator.

*note: It is safe to remove the entire Adobe Illustrator CS5 Settings folder. This folder contains various preferences that can be regenerated.*

Comment: Worth the loss of settings i'd say. That did the trick though!